# Error in combn(levels(Factor), 2) : n < m using EcoUtils adonis.pair function

Tags: r

Long time viewer, first time poster.

I am having a hard time figuring out why my code is not working using EcoUtil's adonis.pair function.

My code is

> adonis.pair(vegdist(rar.trim.Dataframe, method = "bray"), treatment.IDer$treatment, nper=1000)

But I keep getting this error

> Error in combn(levels(Factor), 2) : n < m

rar.trim.Dataframe is a 13 row dataframe with 178 variables, and treatment.IDer is a 13 row single column dataframe designating the treatment groups. All the rownames are the same for each of these dataframes, and in the same order. What am I doing wrong here? It looks so straight forward, and works perfectly when I use the Dune dataset so it can't be the function.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This may be because some group have less than 2 elements.  You may subset those cases before applying.

Comment: @akrun my treatments all have at least two, unless you mean something something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. My treatment.IDer$treatment was set to character, not factor, hence the error. The following code set it to a factor with the appropriate levels.

> treatment.IDer$treatment=as.factor(treatment.IDer$treatment)

Code works perfectly now!